# Java Map w @NonNull Value Type and @Nullable get() method result?

Tags: java, null, annotations, nullable

I have a method returning a custom Map implementation, whose entries consist entirely of non-null keys and values, so I would like to add type annotations in order to indicate that clients may iterate over the Map.Entry's without having to check them for null values: Map<@NonNull String,@NonNull String>

The problem is that the Map.get method API specifies that null be returned for any attempt to retrieve a value for a key which isn't present in the Map, and annotating my get method implementation to return a @Nullable String generates a compiler warning that the return type is then incompatible with the @NonNull return specified by the Map.

I understand that a Map.get API created today might perhaps return a java.util.Optional result or throw a NoSuchElementException, but, being beholden to the existing Collections API, is it possible to remain compliant with the get method specification and also specify that my Map contains only @NonNull values?

Much Thanks.

Comment: This isn't quite clear.  Disallowing null values is a separate concern from never attempting to lookup keys that aren't in the map.  Which are you talking about?

Comment: I want to specify that null values aren't allowed in the Map.  But, if I do that, I'm apparently also implying the get method won't return null, which isn't the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Map API is not really compatible with null annotations. [Map.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) returns the generic type V, even when you define V to be @NonNull, which then violates the API since null must be an allowable return value.

This is a [known limitation](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=437881#c1) of null annotations, and will probably only be resolved when [nullity profiles for libraries](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331651) are implemented. Until then, the only workarounds are to check with [Map.containsKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) before getting a value instead of checking the value afterwards for null, or just avoid using @NonNull on map value types.

Comment: Yeah, I've been subscribed to that nullity profiles bug since it became clear to me that null annotations (even with the type annotations Java 8 brings) weren't quite ready for primetime yet without them, since, without those profiles, my code is so littered with warnings from core Java API calls as to make the analysis largely useless.  Given that, I've disabled null analysis by default, but I'm still attempting to write code using the annotations, as I find it helps me design API's which are more conscious of correct null handling.

Comment: Given that I'm writing all the annotations with the assumption that they'll eventually implement those profiles, and the fact that my Map really shouldn't contain any null values, maybe I'll just go ahead and annotate the value as NonNull, and view the fact that the get method isn't recognized as Nullable as yet another analysis bug/limitation that needs to be fixed before I enable this stuff by default.

Comment: Yeah, I've also had a lot of trouble with it, especially now with streams (try filtering out null!). If nothing else, you definitely have to ignore "Unchecked conversion from non-annotated type to `@NonNull` type". I've managed to work around other warnings/errors so far with the help of a few utility methods to convert `@Nullable T` to `@NonNull T`, similar to Optional's "orElse" methods.

Comment: This is not a limitation of null annotations.  It's just a limitation of Eclipse's implementation of them.  Other tools handle maps precisely, without issuing false positive warnings and without the need to clutter code with extraneous calls to `Map.containsKey`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be referring to Eclipse's implementation of nullity checking.  You are right that it does not reason precisely about calls to `Map.get`.

If more precise reasoning about calls to `Map.get` is important to you, you might want to consider using a different nullity checker.  For example, the [Nullness Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#nullness-checker) that is built on the Checker Framework handles your case.  It treats the return value of `Map.get` as non-null if [the key is in the map](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#map-key-checker) and all the elements of the map are non-null.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple library that can be used as a work around:

```
package xxxx;

import java.util.*;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.*;

public class NullUtil
{
    @SuppressWarnings ("null")
    public static <@NonNull K, @NonNull T> @NonNull Optional<@Nullable T> get (@NonNull Map<@NonNull K, @NonNull T> m, @NonNull K key)
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable(m.get(key));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings ("null")
    public static <@NonNull K, @NonNull T> @NonNull T getOrThrow (@NonNull Map<@NonNull K, @NonNull T> m, @NonNull K key)
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable(m.get(key)).orElseThrow(
            () -> new RuntimeException("Map does not contain element '" + key + "'"));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings ("null")
    public static <@NonNull K, @NonNull T> @Nullable T getOrNull (@NonNull     Map<@NonNull K, @NonNull T> m, @NonNull K key)
    {
        return Optional.ofNullable(m.get(key)).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

And here are some example uses:

```
package xxxx;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.*;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;
import org.junit.*;

public class NullUtilTest
{
    @Before
    public void setup ()
    {
        _m.put("a", "va");
        _m.put("b", "vb");
        _m.put("c", "vc");
    }

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings ("null")
    public void testOptional ()
    {
        assertTrue(NullUtil.get(_m, "a").isPresent());
        assertFalse(NullUtil.get(_m, "x").isPresent());

        assertEquals("va", NullUtil.get(_m, "a").orElse(null));
        assertEquals(null, NullUtil.get(_m, "x").orElse(null));

    }

    @Test
    public void testOrNull ()
    {
        assertEquals("va", NullUtil.getOrNull(_m, "a"));
        assertEquals(null, NullUtil.getOrNull(_m, "x"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrThrow ()
    {
        assertEquals("va", NullUtil.getOrThrow(_m, "a"));

        try
        {
            assertEquals("vx", NullUtil.getOrThrow(_m, "x"));
            fail();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            assertEquals("Map does not contain element 'x'", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private final @NonNull Map<@NonNull String, @NonNull String> _m = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

When you have this error with null value or key:

```
c.f.j.c.JsonGenerationException:  
  Null key for a Map not allowed in JSON (use a converting NullKeySerializer?)     
            at c.f.j.d.s.i.FailingSerializer.serialize(FailingSerializer.java:36)
```

You solve override Serialize method like:

```
class MySerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {     
        public MyDtoNullKeySerializer() {
             this(null);}     
             public MySerializer(Class<Object> t) { 
                super(t);     
            }     
      @Override   
      public void serialize(Object nullKey, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,SerializerProvider unused) 
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException { 
            jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("");    
        } 
}
```

For example complete see here:
https://lentux-informatica.com/jackson-problema-con-maps-e-valori-null/